# Logstash not updating last run metadata file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

In my Logstash I want to download from a database the most recent data using `:sql_last_value` in a query and `tracking_column` option in conf file. I've set 
`last_run_metadata_path` because I have 2 pipelines for the same table but Logstash saved last date only once or stopped saving new dates and now I can see in logs that it runs queries with the same `:sql_last_value` from metadata file.

That's how my conf file looks like, it has many jdbc inputs and one of them below:

```
  jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/logstash/lib/ojdbc8.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => ""
        jdbc_user => ""
        jdbc_password => ""
        schedule => "*/15 * * * *"
        statement_filepath => "/etc/logstash/queries/UAT/transactions_UAT.sql"
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => 'sys_created_on'
        tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
        last_run_metadata_path => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/lastrun_metadata/transactions_uat_metadata"
        tags => ["transactions_uat"]
  }
```

Content of the metadata file:

```
--- 2018-05-26 08:41:55.000000000 -04:00
```

I can see in the logs that Logstash always uses the same date from the metadata file and newer updates it:

```
select * from snc_uat.syslog_transaction0007
 where "sys_created_on" >= TIMESTAMP '2018-05-26 08:41:55.000000 -04:00'
```

Logstash is working and is downloading recent data but unnecessarily processes data that already exists. Why is Logstash not updating metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your comparison operator is **greater than or equal to** i.e. `>=` please change it to `>` and it will fix your problem.
Hope it helps.