# logstash not updating :sql_last_value meta data file

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I have a pretty standard JDBC configuration for logstash, but **suddenly** it has stopped updating:sql_last_value.
Want to understand what could be the scenario when it can happen. There are also no error logs at all too.

I have looked  the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50603322/logstash-not-updating-last-run-metadata-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351844/logstash-jdbc-last-run-metadata-file-not-updating)

both are not applicable in my case

Comment: have you tried restarting?

Comment: yes. it works after restarting but suddenly stops working.

Comment: can you see any unusual logging in the log files? can you share the logtrace for the pipeline?